# Camera intent saves images to gallery in specific devices

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, android-file, android-camera-intent

I'm using camera intent to save image to specific folder, but in Lenovo devices image duplicate is saved in gallery. How to avoid saving image in gallery and save only in provided folder?

Here is code i'm using

```
    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,
                        "com.example.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
    }


    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
```

Comment: "in Lenovo devices image is saved in gallery too" -- a gallery is an app, not a filesystem directory. Do you mean that the image is being indexed by the `MediaStore`, and so a gallery app is showing the image from the location where you asked the image to be saved? If so, that was Lenovo's decision, and other camera apps are welcome to do the same thing. You might consider using `FileProvider` and have the camera save the image in `getFilesDir()`, so `MediaStore` cannot index it at all.

Comment: gallery isn't showing image from the location i asked the image to be saved.The fact is that There are created 2 copies of image, one is saved where i specified to be saved and one is saved in DCIM/Camera folder and gallery grabs that image from DCIM/Camera folder. I want to avoid saving image copy in DCIM/Camera folder.

Comment: OK, that too is up to the camera app. The developers of the camera app either did this intentionally or have a bug, neither of which you can change. Moreover, your code could be using any one of hundreds of camera apps, depending on what the user has installed. Your options are either to live with this behavior or to stop using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` and take photos another way. For example, you could use a camera library, such as CameraX, Fotoapparat, or CameraKit-Android.